# Separate JSON Inner Elements From One Another

Tags: jquery, json

Given that **I CANNOT** change the server-side code that outputs this JSON:

```
[
  {
    test_id: "1",
    test_name: "Diagnostic Test 1"
  },
  {
    test_id: "2",
    test_name: "Test 1"
  },
  {
    test_id: "3",
    test_name: "Test 2"
  }
]
```

What is the best way to create buttons in which the value is the first part of  the inner element, and the actual text displayed on the button is the second part of the inner element?

```
<div id="testList">
   <button value="test_id">test_name</button>
   <button value="test_id">test_name</button>
   <button value="test_id">test_name</button>
</div>
```

Currently I'm doing this:

```
$.getJSON( "tests.json", "json" )
    .done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(){
            $.each(this, function(name, value){
                $("#testList").append('<button>'+ value +'</button>');
            })
        })
    });
```

Which outputs the buttons separately:

```
<div id="testList">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>Diagnostic Test 1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>Test 1</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>Test 2</button>
</div>
```

**Remember**: I cannot change the JSON!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your inner `$.each` - the outer loop addressing `data` has access to both properties of each object:

```
$.getJSON( "tests.json", "json" )
    .done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, d){
            $("#testList").append('<button value="' + d.test_id + '">'+ d.test_name+'</button>');
        })
    });
```

Note that this isn't an entirely robust way of generating elements, depending on how much you trust the source of the data and if they're supposed to contain just plain text.  Something like the following would be better:

```
var b = $('<button>');
b.val(d.test_id);
b.text(d.test_name);
$("#testList").append(b);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - works like a charm. Will accept when time limit passes

Comment: Note that this isn't entirely robust - ideally you want to escape `test_id` and `test_name`, depending on how much you trust the source of the data.  Have edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON( "tests.json", "json" )
    .done(function(data) {

            $.each(this, function(ind,element){
                $("#testList").append(element.test_id + '<button>'+ element.test_name+'</button>');
            })

    });
```